# Using Supabase point-in-time recovery for undo redo

Tags: supabase, undo-redo, pitr

I'm creating an application in which users should be able to travel back in time on documents, and pick an older doc state to set as a new one. Kind of like a nice undo-redo functionality, with history all the way back to the start of the document.

Now I'm reading about [point-in-time-recovery (PITR)](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/platform/backups#point-in-time-recovery). Can I use this to travel back in time on one part of the db? (One document that Has Many paragraphs)? Or is this only to put the complete DB back in a previous state, for actual emergencies?

I've read about [bitemporal data](https://martinfowler.com/articles/bitemporal-history.html), but I just wondered if this may be a more ready-to-go solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the latter. Supabase point in time recovery is to put the entire database back to a state sometime in the past, and it would not be suited for your usecase.